# Html with parameters GET

Tags: html

I have a doubt about this sentence in html:

```
    <a href="http://www.donate.co?amount=100&amp;destination=MessageTable/">
```

and this:

```
     <a href="http://www.donate.co?amount=100&destination=MessageTable/">
```

This sentence pass paramaters with GET. But I don't undertand because in the first sentence put & amp; and the second sentence put & only.

Thank you,

regards,
javi

Answer (score 2):

In HTML `&` means "Start of an entity / character reference".

`&lt;` is how you say *greater than* instead of saying *start of tag*.

`&amp;` is how you say *ampersand* instead of saying *start of entity*

Comment: Ok, If I want to use this concept for doing an atttack XSRF. I can do it. How could I do it? Thank you so much

Comment: You can't. Entity escaping has nothing to do with cross site request forgery.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution.